# Using Outlook Contact Form

Tags: vb.net, outlook, contacts

I am using the Outlook Contact Form from my application to allow the user to create a new contact. When the user saves the contact or closes the form, the instance of outlook closes as well. How can I keep outlook from closing, I am not done with the object and it takes a few seconds to open another instance of outlook?

```
Dim outlookApp as new Outlook.Application
Dim newContact as New Outlook.ContactItem
newContact = outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olContactItem)
newContact.Display(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook exits when its last window (explorer or inspector) closes even if there are outstanding references to its objects.

Try to keep a reference to an Outlook explorer (it does not have to be visible) if there isn't one open. Off the top of my head:

```
dim explorer as Outlook.Explorer
...
explorer = outlookApp.ActiveExplorer
If (explorer Is Nothing) Then
  session = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  session.Logon
  folder = session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  explorer = folder.GetExplorer
End If
```